# Creating asp.net membership pages in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, deployment

We have some asp.net pages that include the asp.net membership user controls for forms based authentication and would like to make use of these in a SharePoint MOSS environment.

Can anyone suggest the best place to deploy these and the best method for deployment, I was hoping to use solution packages to deploy them to the root of the site.

Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 3):

A good technique I've used previously is to make a copy of the standard SharePoint login page and make changes to that. There is an [article by Damon Armstrong](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/customizing-the-login-page-in-sharepoint-2007/) that describes how to do this. His article is good apart from making a copy of the _layouts folder which I believe is overkill. You can just put your amended copy of login.aspx and login.master in its own folder under `LAYOUTS` in the "12 Hive". Then configure ASP.NET to use these custom files with this directive in the FBA site's web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/CustomFBA/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

As the custom pages are going under the Layouts folder they should be trivial to add to a solution file.

Comment: Alex, sorry I posted my comments to the second post by accident. Would appreciate your thoughts deploying the pages to the root of the site.

Comment: @orl78: I've never deployed a login page in this way. It should work provided users have anonymous access to the login page itself. It's possible to manage permissions on individual items so this should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a good candidate for an Application Page, deployed to the 12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder. MSDN has a Visual How-To here: [Creating an Application Page in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732.aspx). At a minimum you would need to set your master page to ~/_layouts/application.master and deploy the assembly with your WSP.

Comment: I think we are trying to have them in the root of the site though, for example http://sharepoint/registeruser.aspx rather than the url having the _layouts visible. This article seems like a possibility http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx

Comment: I've also read that securing the pages in the _layouts might be tricky

Comment: That's the other option, and AC's article is exactly what you need. Securing _layouts is not necessarily tricky, just different. Generally, use _layouts if you need to access the page from multiple sites and a feature-deployed page if not.